# Стоит ли использовать многопоточность с libevent, libuv, libev?

Tags: c, многопоточность, libev, libevent

Стоит ли форкаться или создавать потоки при работе с libevent, libuv, libev? Если да, то в каких случаях(или в какой момент выполнения программы, например при обработке конкретного события). Или же лучше выполнять всё в основном потоке программы? Задача - свой сервер с применением данных технологий.

Comment: Применение этих библиотек никак не влияет на решение о использовании или не использовании потоков/процессов. Это зависит исключительно от решаемой задачи, которую надо рассматривать комплексно с учетом всех нюансов

Comment: @Mike не могли бы привести какие нибудь примеры(хотя бы приблизительно) в каких случаях стоит использовать многопоточность, а в каких нет? Я видимо их не совсем допонимаю, но на мой взгляд распараллеливание для них вообще не нужно, поэтому и хочу прояснить для себя на примерах.

Comment: Например вы по запросу клиента начинаете выполнять долгую вычислительную задачу, остальные клиенты в это время ждут. Или отправляете запрос в БД, я сомневаюсь, что вы сможете подружить библиотеку работы с БД с этой асинхронностью. Или вам не хватает количества открытых сокетов на один процесс. и в конце концов когда у вас тысяча коннектов какой бы короткой обработка каждого из запросов не была, но обработка на нескольких ядрах быстрее и уменьшает время отклика

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Многопоточность нужна. Как минимум это позволит полнее утилизировать возможности современных процессоров, позволит больше обслужить клиентов/подключений. Тут вопрос не стоит. А вот какой подход использовать: запускать процессы-воркеры с супервизором или работать в отдельных потоках - зависит от потребностей. В частности, libevent очень хочет, что бы вы использовать многопроцессный подход, а libev предоставляет механизмы по синхронизации и работы со многими потоками и непринуждённо работает и в многопоточной среде.

Стоит отметить, что синхронизация требуется для внутренних структур этих библиотек, сами механизмы реакторов (тот же epoll), зачастую потокобезопасны сами по себе.

Ну а подходы: процесс или поток... Тут нужно планировать и смотреть на свои потребности: у процессов сложнее организовать взаимодействие, но получаете значительно большую надёжность (если упал один процесс, он не повлияет на другие), плюс отсутствие необходимости в синхронизации внутри процесса. С потоками всё то же самое, но с другим знаком.